# how to build sign up user with extra field(dropdown list filled from database) from another table?

Tags: django

i want make sign-up for users with a extra field that will be populated from another model during creation , my three fields in registration are `username`, `password`, `structure_designation` which is supposed to be a drop down list getting data from related table.

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from immob.models import Structure
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
structure=models.ForeignKey(Structure,
on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
if created:
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
instance.profile.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working Example**:

Firstly you'll need to use django's [**`AbstractUser`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/) to extend `User` model rather than using `OnetoOnefield`.

`Models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Structure(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    structure = models.ForeignKey(Structure, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Then in **`Settings.py`**, you need to point to model which will be used as Auth_Model in order to authenticate users and create the same.So Add this in `Settings`.

**`AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.CustomUser'`**

To create user we can simply use pre-provided method called [**`UserCreationForm`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm). Now the benefit of using Abstractuser is you don't need to implement `ModelChoiceField`.

`Forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import CustomUser, Structure


class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("username", "structure", "password1", "password2")
```

`Views.py`

```
from .forms import UserCreateForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic

class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'app/signup.html'
```

`app/signup.html`

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

Simple form that is generated by django and then connect all this with urls and you're good to go.

Comment: but i have in Immob app the models.py   and the models who writes is in compte app                                                       
   # Create your models here.                                                                                  class Structure(models.Model):
    structure_code=models.CharField(max_length=1)
    structure_desig=models.CharField(max_length=350)
class Service(models.Model):        structure_id=models.ForeignKey    (Structure,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
 service_desig=models.CharField(max_length=350)

Comment: It doesn't matter if the related model code is in another app, while your imports are correct you should be able to see data in dropdown while sign-up.

Comment: no i try to understand how can i do it because there is a specific logic i need t explain all logic for understanding me correctly and in stackoverflow i can't put all code because is limited

Comment: you can explain all the logic here, that's why stack overflow exists. Edit your question with the complete logic.